# How can I close dropdown if another dropdown is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dynamic contents like sort of a news-feed and each element has a dropdown menu.
I am able to toggle the dropdown-menu of the exact element I click on and when I click outside or anywhere else on the window it closes the menu which is nice.
but problem arise when I click on another dropdown element. The previously clicked menu doesn't close instead it stays on the same page.

what I am trying to say is
when I click multiple dropdown elements, I have them all showing,
it only closes or disappears when I click outside of element.

For instance
When I click on dropdown-1, then click on dropdown-2, they both display at the same window. How do I close dropdown 1 while dropdown 2 is open instead of having them both open.

How can I toggle each dropdown as I click. I am unable to attach video to this post, but I have added an image to help clarify my question.

[image]

This is an example of my JQuery code to toggle dropdown.

```
/* toggle dropdown options */
$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-toggle", function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $(this).siblings().toggleClass('show');
});

/* // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it */
$(window).click(function (e) {
 if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn') ) {
    var dropdowns = $('.dropdown-content');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if ($(openDropdown).hasClass("show") ) {
            $(openDropdown).removeClass("show");
        }
    }
 }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve this problem.

what I did was to hide all divs that may be visible then toggle the dropdown I clicked to show its content.

```
$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-toggle", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        // hide all dropdown that may be visible
        var i;
        var dropdowns = $('.dropdown-content');
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if ($(openDropdown).hasClass("show")) {
                $(openDropdown).removeClass("show");
            }
        }
        
        // toggle the dropdown 
        $(this).siblings().toggleClass('show');
    });
```

Comment: Note that the code in the `for` loop can be replaced with just `$('.dropdown-content.show').removeClass('show');`. There is no need to loop when calling methods to update the DOM in jQuery.

Comment: In as much as what works work, I will refactor the code. Thanks for suggesting this improvement.